# Is it possible to create both client and server using IIOP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, corba

I'm new to [IIOP.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iiop-net/).

I have done a Adder app using IIOP.Net ( Server is written in Java and client is C#). Now I want to create both client and server using IIOP.Net written in C# ( I know there are many easier ways to do that but I just want to use IIOP.Net).

What I did is:

1. Create Server. OK

Because my client is C#, I don't have the idl file to compile to the cls, so  I did a bad trick here. I create a libary that is the implementation of my corba object, then build it to a .dll file, finally copy it to my client project ( add references...).

1. Create client. OK
2. Run Server. OK
3. Run Client. Not OK

I got an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'omg.org.CosNaming.NamingContext_package.NotFound' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

at line:

```
Adder a = (Adder) nm.resolve(nameService);
//where Adder is implementation of corba object (in library).
```

I have no idea to fix that. I googled it but does not give me any expected result.
Hope to see your answers soon.
Thank you.

Comment: Could someone please give me an advice?

Comment: Is this your first time using name service? -- "I know there are many easier ways to do that but I just want to use IIOP.Net". There is not, CORBA is easy and IIOP.NET is a nice project.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the first time for me in Distributed programming.

Comment: @Makah: Could you please tell me how to make both client and server using IIOP.Net. I implemented the Server. Next, compile to idl ( use idl to cls tool), then I compile to cls ( use cls to idl). Finally, I add references the .dll that i have just got before. But It seems Visual does not see my .dll

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I mean to compile to idl ( use cls to idl)....

Comment: (a) Create IDL, (b) compile IDL to CLS (that generates dll), (c) go to you VS and add reference, (d) create an IIOP channel and good luck

Comment: @Makah: Thank you. But I did that steps except I don't create IDL file. I use CLS to IDL to generate the idl file from the interface I create in server side (Adder.cs for instance). Your steps is perfect when server is written in Java.

Comment: @Makah: Now I copy the file that defines my interface from Server to Client, and It works but It's just a bad trick, right?.

Comment: I prefer to make my IDL alone, but you can use CLS to IDL. It's not a bad trick. The dll needs to be used in both sides. If you want to learn more abou CORBA this is a good book to start: http://goo.gl/pNdIKc

Comment: @Makah: Thank you. I use CLS to IDL ( but VS seem does not see any interface in .dll). I have to edit the idl file and compile again to make it work. By the way. How can I set hostname ( I want my server runs on other machine) for my server. I see at the constructor of IiopChannel but dont see the hostname param?

Comment: Try to read the documentation and IIOP.NET forum. You can even try to see IIOP.NET Examples